# -to position parameter in ffmpeg doesn’t specify timestamp, acts as duration instead

Tags: video, ffmpeg

If I try to cut out a section of the video from 30th second till 60th second (duration of 30 seconds), I would usually do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i inputVideo.mp4 -c copy -t 00:00:30 outputVideo.mp4
```

How do I specify a final position instead of duration? I tried with -to which documentation says the following about:

> -to position (input/output)
>   Stop writing the output or reading the input at position. position must be a time duration specification, see (ffmpeg-utils)the Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.
>   -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.

But even if I use the -to parameter, it still behaves as a duration would:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i inputVideo.mp4 -c copy -to 00:01:00 outputVideo.mp4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Specify `-to` as an input option:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -to 00:01:00 -i inputVideo.mp4 -c copy outputVideo.mp4
```

---

or `-ss` as an output option

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -ss 30 -to 1:00 OUTPUT
```

---

or use `-copyts`

```
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 30 -i INPUT -to 1:00 OUTPUT
```

Comment: The missing insight is that ffmpeg resets input timestamps to start from 0. So, the input seek point has timestamp 0 when sent for output.